# How to link Gmail with Airflow 2.8.2 running on a docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, airflow

I am struggling to connect my Gmail account to Airflow. I've followed ChatGPT suggestions and searched in this site for solutions but i haven't crossed upon one that addresses my context, and I don't know what else ask to chat gpt.

I am working in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS jammy. I installed Airflow with docker following the instructions in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTaytcxy2Ck&t=335s. I can open the Airflow UI. I already generated App Password through Google, which I pasted in the Admin connections section at the Airflow UI. Specifically i have the following configuration:

```
Conn Id = smtp_gmail_conn
Conn Type = email
Host = smtp.gmail.com
Port = 587
Login = my email which I dont show here
Password = the app password google gave me 
Is Encrypted = False
Is Extra Enctrypted = False
```

Earlier on, chat-gpt suggested adding to the yml file the following code in the airflow-webserver part:

```
  <<: *airflow-common-env
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: smtp.gmail.com
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: 587
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: your_email@gmail.com
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: your_app_password
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS: "True"
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL: "False"
```

Yet it did not work, so I deleted those variables from the YAML file.

This is an extract of my task's log file. The error is shown at the bottom:

```
[2024-03-13, 17:26:37 UTC] {task_command.py:423} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: example_email_dag.send_email_task manual__2024-03-13T17:19:27.422265+00:00 [running]> on host bce2c982946e
[2024-03-13, 17:26:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2510} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='my_owner' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='example_email_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='send_email_task' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-03-13T17:19:27.422265+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='3' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2024-03-13T17:19:27.422265+00:00'
[2024-03-13, 17:26:38 UTC] {base.py:83} INFO - Using connection ID 'smtp_gmail_conn' for task execution.
[2024-03-13, 17:26:38 UTC] {email.py:270} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2024-03-13, 17:26:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2728} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 444, in _execute_task
    result = _execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 414, in _execute_callable
    return execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 79, in execute
    send_email(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 80, in send_email
    return backend(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 154, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, conn_id=conn_id, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 272, in send_mime_email
    smtp_conn = _get_smtp_connection(smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_timeout, smtp_ssl)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 316, in _get_smtp_connection
    return smtplib.SMTP(host=host, port=port, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 310, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I understand this error is because the connection is failing to set up. I already double check my app password. I cant find the cfg file so i can't edit it.

This is the code my dag file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

# Define the default_args dictionary to set the default parameters of the DAG.
default_args = {
    'owner': 'my_owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 3, 13),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Instantiate the DAG with the provided default_args.
dag = DAG(
    'example_email_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='An example DAG sending an email using an Airflow connection',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

# Define the task within the DAG.

# Task: Send an email using the specified SMTP connection
send_email_task = EmailOperator(
    task_id='send_email_task',
    to='max.al97@hotmail.com',
    subject='Airflow Email Example',
    html_content='<p>This is the body of the email.</p>',
    dag=dag,
    # Specify the connection ID created in Admin > Connections
    conn_id='smtp_gmail_conn',  # Replace with your connection ID
)

# Define the task dependencies.
send_email_task

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

# Define the default_args dictionary to set the default parameters of the DAG.
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Max Alejandro',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 3, 13),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Instantiate the DAG with the provided default_args.
dag = DAG(
    'example_email_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='An example DAG sending an email using an Airflow connection',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

# Define the task within the DAG.

# Task: Send an email using the specified SMTP connection
send_email_task = EmailOperator(
    task_id='send_email_task',
    to='max.al97@hotmail.com',
    subject='Airflow Email Example',
    html_content='<p>This is the body of the email.</p>',
    dag=dag,
    # Specify the connection ID created in Admin > Connections
    conn_id='smtp_gmail_conn',  # Replace with your connection ID
)

# Define the task dependencies.
send_email_task
```

I'll really appreciate any advice, help, suggestion.

Comment: can you pls try the suggestions in this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77916588/airflow-smtp-not-working-with-docker-section-key-smtp-smtp-user-not-found-in/77917662#77917662

Comment: pls add those env variables in the x-airflow-common: environment section
In my case i had specified the username and credentials only in the Connection :


    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: 'smtp.office365.com'
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: '587'
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS: 'True'
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL: 'False'
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: 'svc.airflowtest@domain.com'

Comment: @subram When you say "i had specified the username and credentials only in the Connection" you mean in the Admin>Connection section in the Airflow UI? My other question is: should i keep the gmail connection I set up earlier, or should i delete it for the moment?

Comment: I added username/credential in the default email connection 'smtp_default' via the Admin->Connection in the UI. You can use that gmail connection you created.

Comment: @subram So I run the DAG and it run successfully, then checked out the inbox at the wpoven.com link you sent but it shows nothing apart of the "email_address_i_sent_mail@hotmail.com  inbox" string. So I guess it doesn't work. I kept the gmail connection at the Connections section in the UI as you told me. What should I do next? I really appreciate your time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put config in yaml into airflow-webserver but into x-airflow-common configs:
[image of where to put smtp configs in docker-compose.yml for airflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pckvu.jpg)
Above I've put all the smtp config into a separate .env file and just imported this file in a right place.

As for the env.file contents, it's this:

```
AIRFLOW__SMTP__EMAIL_BACKEND: 'airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: 'smtp.gmail.com'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS: 'true'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL: 'false'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: 'your_email69@gmail.com'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: '587'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: 'your_pass'
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: 'your_email@gmail.com'
```

But I think it should work without the first and last line too.

And it doesn't need any connection configuration in admin UI, nor passing it like you did in the task:

```
# Specify the connection ID created in Admin > Connections
conn_id='smtp_gmail_conn',  # Replace with your connection ID
```

All you have to provide to EmailOperator is:

```
task_id=
to=
subject=
html_content=
```

Of course after adding config to yaml, don't forget to restart containers.